# Facebook is not login in my app

Tags: iphone

Hi i am using like feature in my app on Xcode 4.6 in Xib files but on clicking facebook is not login. While on the other side it is login when i do in another app in Story Board. Please guide me if any one knows about it.

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        _facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"129649123867187" andDelegate:self];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.facebookLikeView.href = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://sis.uol.edu.pk/sis/MainForms/login.aspx"];
    self.facebookLikeView.layout = @"button_count";
    self.facebookLikeView.showFaces = NO;
    //    self.facebookLikeView.alpha = 1;
    [self.facebookLikeView load];
    facebookLikeView.delegate = self;
}

#pragma mark FBSessionDelegate methods

- (void)fbDidLogin {
    self.facebookLikeView.alpha = 1;
    [self.facebookLikeView load];
}

- (void)fbDidLogout {
    self.facebookLikeView.alpha = 1;
    [self.facebookLikeView load];
}

#pragma mark FacebookLikeViewDelegate methods

- (void)facebookLikeViewRequiresLogin:(FacebookLikeView *)aFacebookLikeView {
    [_facebook authorize:[NSArray array]];
}

- (void)facebookLikeViewDidRender:(FacebookLikeView *)aFacebookLikeView {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.5];
    self.facebookLikeView.alpha = 1;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)facebookLikeViewDidLike:(FacebookLikeView *)aFacebookLikeView {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Liked"
                                                    message:@"You liked  my app. Thanks!"
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil] ;
    [alert show];
}

- (void)facebookLikeViewDidUnlike:(FacebookLikeView *)aFacebookLikeView {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Unliked"
                                                    message:@"You unliked my app ."
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil] ;
    [alert show];
}
```

Comment: please post some code....

Comment: you check  FBSession.activeSession.isOpen fbuser is login or not

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be OK, and you're using code of [FacebookLikeView](https://github.com/brow/FacebookLikeView), when I tried to implement the same in my application it won't show up the login because *I forgot to bind **FacebookLikeView** with IB.* Another problem that also happened to me was, You may need to cut `_facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"129649123867187" andDelegate:self];`
 line from `init` method and put it into `viewDidLoad` like below, because it won't called up in my case!

```
if(!_facebook)
{
    _facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"129649123867187" andDelegate:self];
}
```

I believe that you don't forget to set delegate for `FBConnect`, `FacebookLikeViewDelegate` and `FBSessionDelegate`

If you still can't solve out the problem, then it may be with your`Facebook App ID`do try to use the default app id given there in source code, it should work!